# ZPL2 - Printer is compressing barcodes when oriented vertically, making them unreadable

Tags: label, zebra-printers, zpl, barcode-printing, zpl-ii

Currently, I'm trying to switch a barcode to print vertically. The issue I'm seeing is the vertical barcode is printing slightly compressed. The horizontal barcode scans fine, but the vertical one is a muddy mess with the bars running together.

The vertical barcode prints about 10-15px shorter than the horizontal one does, so I'm thinking this is related to the label length. I set the printer to continuous with a label length of 800, the same as the label width. This fixed the issue in a preview, but the label still prints wrong. Image and code attached.

Printer is a GK420T.

[Barcodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyhqz.png)

The code is as follows:

```
^XA
^FWN
^FO300,10
^BY1,3,40
^BCR,40,Y,N,N

^FD123456ABCD^FS
^FO350,10
^BY1,3^BCN,40,Y,N,N
^FD123456ABCD^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the print speed?  It looks like the label is "over burning" so increasing print speed may help.  You can control that on the printer panel or via ZPL using `^PR`.

Comment: I'll give that a shot - however, I'm not sure it'll solve the scaling problem. Do you have any idea what could cause the vertical barcode to be shorter than the horizontal one?

Comment: You can also turn down the darkness. When using vertical barcodes it is easy to set the darkness too high as you tend to judge the darkness on how the text looks. So in the end this is not a scaling issue but rather the overburn.

Answer (score 0):

I see these answers are already in the question's comments, but I concur.

This seems to be a problem with the print speed and/or darkness. Rotating a barcode will have no impact on its readability like that.

Also, make sure you are using the correct direct thermal/transfer setting. If you still have problems, transfer type labels are much better than thermal for readability and durability, although you do have to then deal with the ribbon.